# Jquery not defined in angular 6 after upgrade

Tags: jquery, angular, angular5, angular6

I recently upgraded my application `from Angular-5 to Angular-6` and Jquery suddenly stopped working.
It was working fine in Angular 5 but no longer working in Angular 6.
`The error states: $(...).DataTable is not a function`

Comment: Is it a TypeScript error or is it happening at runtime in the browser?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel It happens at runtime in the browser

Comment: How are you including that jQuery plugin? Is it in your `angular.json` file in the `scripts` array?

Comment: It may be because with import issue and also use of jQery in Angular application is bad practice.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Yes. I include it in the angular.json file in the scripts array.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I successfully managed to make it work by adding

` import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'datatables.net'; `

in a parent component

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have jQuery added into your `angular.json` file

```
 "scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
 ]
```

And make sure to add the following to your component

```
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;
```

Outside the export class.

By the way it's not the best practice to use jQuery with Angular, I recommend you using a directive for the plugin instead:

you can check it out here: [Angular Datatables directive](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome)